# can't load ajax on IE6 & IE7

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

The code below is an ajax create function which is written in JS.

this works on `Firefox`, `Safari` and `Chrome` perfectly but doesn't work on `IE6` & `IE7`.

How can fix my code to load ajax?

```
function ajaxCreateRequest() {
    var request = false;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest;
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    if(!request)
        alert("This Browser doesn't support my page!");

    return request;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or something? What does `it does not work` mean?

Comment: well literally. it doesn't work. an error says can't load ajax.js, which contains that code.

Comment: Do you get `This Browser doesn't support my page!` ?

Comment: @Hoon - "can't load ajax.js". Are you saying the whole script isn't even being loaded at all? Is "ajax.js" the code you're showing us, or something else?

Comment: I feel he has posted only half of his code above.

Comment: well, actually this is the entire code for calling ajax. I took this function from my ajax book. anyways, IE says, can't load ajax.js(I think IE can't load only ajax.js the code above).

Comment: when I use ajax, I load the code above and declare like this: var Variable = ajaxCreateRequest(); Variable.open(something); ... Variable.send(null); This works well on Chrome, Safari and FF.

Comment: I really can't understand why IE says like can't load ajax,js (ajaxCreateRequest()) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I do not foresee/observe any conspicuous issue in your above posted code, why not use existing javascript framework (they make up excellent javascript abstractions) like

1) [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)

2) [Mootools](http://mootools.net/)

3) [Prototype.js](http://prototypejs.org/)

If you try to write this on your own by using the archaic code that you have posted above, you'll have to burn your fingers while making it cross-browser compatible.

Read up more on jQuery AJAX [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find which part of my code has a problem though, I applied jQuery ajax() instead of my freaking code.